# How to Junit test a try catch block in my code

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I have a class with couple of methods and each with a try catch block to look for any exceptions.

The code as follows:

```
public ResponseEntity get() {

    try {
        .....
    } catch (Exception e) {

        output = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    return output;
}
```

and I came up with a test case using Mokito to test the above scenario but confused how to enter into catch block of the above

```
@Test
public void testgetAllUsers_withoutexecp() {
    when(sMock.getAll()).thenReturn(someList);
    Assert.assertTrue(result.getStatusCode() ==  HttpStatus.OK );
}
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testgetAllUsers_execp() {
    when(sMock.getAll()).thenReturn(null);
    Assert.assertFalse(result.getStatusCode() ==  HttpStatus.OK );

}
```

I tried to raise a NullPointerException but still the catch block is left out in codecoverage (by which I assume it is not been tested). please help me to write a Junit test case for this to enter exception. I am very new to all these topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise exception using `thenThrow` clause of `Mockito`:

```
when(serviceMock.getAllUser()).thenThrow(new NullPointerException("Error occurred"));
```

and then assert like this:

```
Assert.assertTrue(result.getStatusCode() ==  HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expecting NullPointerException makes no sense. This will never happen, because you catch exceptions.

Instead, test for AppConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE9
and  HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR